# How to map a key to a file explorer shell extension?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have a file explorer shell extension called "Copy File Path" or "Copy Folder Path", depending on which pane I am in in file explorer, which copies the full path of a file or a folder to the clipboard. Because it's very handy for me, I use it many times during the day.

To make it more productive, I would like to assign a function key to it instead of using the right mouse click context menu, looking for it in the menu (big menu because of many extensions) and selecting it. The way I want to use it is select the file with the mouse and hit the function key.

Is there a utility or tool, tray taskmaybe, which can add this functionality to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Create a new text file and have the extension be .ahk so script.ahk is the filename. Paste the following into the script file:

```
+^v::
str := clipboard
clipboard := str
Send, ^v
return
```

Save the file and double click on it to run it. An icon indicating that it's active should show up in your taskbar notification area.

What that'll do is when you press Ctrl+Shift+V it'll convert what is in the clipboard into text and then paste it. What this allows you to do is do a regular Ctrl+C on a file or a directory in explorer and then a Ctrl+Shift+V in notepad (or whatever) and get the string of the filepath.